# How to send data to gohtml template

Tags: go

I'm trying to learn Golang. I want to do simply sending data to view. But data is does not reaching to main.gohtml. I could not understand the reason. If I print the data out of the `define` it works. But If I want to print data in the `define "content"` (goes to main.gohtml), data is coming empty.

`define "title"` part is working. Just I cant send data with variable. If I delete `{{.text}}` part and write something, it works.

main.go file

```
var tpl *template.Template

func init() {
    tpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("template/*.gohtml"))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/about", fabout)
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
}

func fabout(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    values, isset := r.URL.Query()["text"]

    var value string

    if isset == true {
        value = values[0]
    } else {
        value = ""
    }

    data := map[string]interface{}{
        "text": value,
    }

    tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "about.gohtml", data)
}
```

about.gohtml

```
{{template "main"}}
{{define "title"}}About me{{end}} //this is working
{{define "content"}}{{.text}}{{end}} //this is not working
{{.text}} //this is working
```

main.gohtml

```
{{define "main"}}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>{{template "title"}}</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Page 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Page 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Page 5</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div style="padding:100px 0;">{{template "content"}}</div>

        <footer>
            this is footer
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
{{end}}
```

Comment: Your code is complete ? or done any modifications before posing here ? ( me too a beginner in `go` ). I tried `go run main.go` but program is just exiting without any output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling a template you need to pass in any necessary data. The syntax from the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Actions) is:

> `{{template "name"}}`  The template with the specified name is executed with nil data.
>
> `{{template "name" pipeline}}`     The template with the specified name is executed with dot set to the value of the pipeline.

So a simple way to fix this is to pass `.` in when calling main:

`{{template "main" .}`

and the same when calling content:

`{{template "content" .}}`

And finally content can use the value:

`{{define "content"}}{{.text}}{{end}}`

note: Using the argument `.` passes all data; you could also just pass `.text` into `main` (and then use `.` when calling  `content` and within content (`{{.}}`).

For a simplified working example see [this playground](https://play.golang.org/p/fJL0mNCarFM).

Answer (score 0):

My Observation is :
here in this below function , variable `value` is empty. there I added line (`value = "Okay"`) for testing and is found working.

```
func fabout(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    values, isset := r.URL.Query()["text"]

    var value string

    if isset == true {
        value = values[0]
    } else {
        value = ""
    }
     value = "Okay" // THIS LINE ADDED EXTRA
    data := map[string]interface{}{
        "text": value,
    }

    tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "about.gohtml", data)
}
```